# Confused on how to structure this program based on Trees/Nodes/Generic types?

Tags: java

So I basically add Person objects to a BinarySearchTree, a class I write myself. I should be able to do things with the BST like find a Person, return its children, etc. and I also have to use generic types for the BST. I also have to create a PersonNode class who's data part is of type Person. I'm confused on how all of this is handled together though. I wrote this so far:

My BST class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public Node<T> root;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public Node<T> find(T key) {
        Node<T> current = root;
        while (current.info != key) {
            if (key.compareTo(current.info) < 0)
                current = current.leftChild;
            else
                current = current.rightChild;
            if (current == null)
                return null;
        }
        return current;
    }
}
```

My Generic Node class:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

public T info;
public T link;
public Node<T> leftChild;
public Node<T> rightChild;

public void displayNode() {
    System.out.print('{');
    System.out.print(info);
    System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(link);
    System.out.print("} ");
}
}
```

And my PersonNode class, which I'm confused as to why this is needed in the first place and what to do with it exactly:

```
public class PersonNode<Person> extends Node{

    public int iData;
    public int dData;
    public Node leftChild;
    public Node rightChild;

    public void displayNode() {
        System.out.print('{');
        System.out.print(iData);
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print(dData);
        System.out.print("} ");
    }
}
```

So am I doing this right so far? What's the use of PersonNode? What else should I need to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can structure it a little bit differently:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>...

public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Node>...

public class Person implements Comparable<Person>...

public class PersonNode extends Node<Person>...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right, you're trying to write custom implementation of BinarySearchTree data structure which can be parameterized with a type. Firstly, I would suggest making the `Node` class an inner class of the `BinarySeachTree` class or package private if you're going to used it in other classes of similar functionality. `Node` class should have a field of type `T` which should hold a value of the node. Also the `PersonNode` class is useless from my point of view - I don't know what are `iData` and `dData` fields - I'm guessing that they are some properties which may be transfered to the Person class.

Finally, although internally your tree will store information in nodes, what you really want to store in the tree is simply 'objects which can be compared somehow' in this case a `Person` object, so instead of coding `BinarySearchTree<T extends Node>` go with `BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>>`

So basically, assuming that you'll reuse the `Node` class, the structure may look like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> { ... }

public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }

public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

Then use the `Node` type internally in the BinarySearchTree to store information:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private Node<T> root;
}
```

and in `Node` class itself

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T> {
    private T value;
    private Node<T> leftChild;
    private Node<T> rightChild;
}
```

General remarks and a friendly advice: don't use public fields, use getters and setters the access fields in your class - go read about data hiding and encapsulation. Long story short it is a very bad practice to use public variables. Use meaningfull field name `iData` and `dData` may have some meaning to you right now, but if you go back to your code in year you'll have to read through it to get what do they really mean in this context.

BTW you don't have to explicitly initialize filed references to null, as they are by default set to null if not stated otherwise. So this can be omitted since it's redundant.

```
public Node<T> root;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
    }
```

Instead I would consider creating a constructor which accepts `T value` as the initial value for the root node of the tree.